# How do I disconnect PyCharm from all debug sessions?

Tags: pycharm

I have about 5 processes/services that make up a single app.  During development, I've got all 5 of them running at once, but when I try to close PyCharm, I get pestered with this annoying dialog 5 times:

[image: annoying dialog]

Is there a way to make PyCharm assume the obvious and kill them all without pestering me?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561673/how-to-disconnect-from-all-debug-sessions), but, in that case, the person was accidentally starting several of the *same* process, so the accepted answer was "don't start so many processes".  In my case, I don't have a choice - I need all 5.